# Randomizing SQL output with specific Order By Clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a SQL query (modified to make smaller for this example) that I would like to have the results randomized but still use the specific Order By clause that I have.

```
with STAGE2 as ( select /*+ FULL(ip) FULL(sx) MATERIALIZE PARALLEL(4) */ distinct
                        sx.claim_nbr,
                        sx.member_nbr
                 from
                        mem_process ip  
                        left outer join visit_x sx on ip.claim_nbr = sx.claim_nbr 
                 where
                        ( (ip.business_unit = 'NC' and ip.carrier = 'MD' and ip.bank = '01'))
                        and ip.paid = 'Y'
                        and sx.paid = 'Y' 
                        and substr(sx.claim_nbr,7,1) not in ('5', '6', '7', '8')
                        and substr(sx.serv_nbr,15,2) = '00'
        )
select distinct
            STAGE1.member_nbr,
            STAGE1.claim_nbr, STAGE1.serv_nbr, STAGE1.ymdeff, STAGE1.ymdend, STAGE1.ymdpaid,
            STAGE1.carrier, STAGE1.bu, STAGE1.bank, STAGE1.PROG_NBR, STAGE1.REGION
from (
select 
                sx.member_nbr,
                sx.claim_nbr, sx.serv_nbr, sx.ymdeff, sx.ymdend, sx.ymdpaid,
                ip.carrier, ip.business_unit as bu, ip.bank, ip.prog_nbr, ip.region
           
from
                STAGE2 
                left outer join mem_process ip on STAGE2.claim_nbr = ip.claim_nbr
                left outer join visit_x sx on ip.claim_nbr = sx.claim_nbr
   
where
                ip.paid = 'Y'
                and sx.paid = 'Y'
                and length(sx.ymdpaid) = 8
    ) STAGE1
order by
  STAGE1.member_nbr,
  STAGE1.serv_nbr
;
```

Is there anyway to return the rows in a random order but still preserve the "member_nbr" and "serv_nbr" ordering? I thought of trying Rand() but I could not get it to work.

Here is the order I currently get:

```
member-a, serv-1-1
member-a, serv-1-2
member-a, serv-2-1
member-a, serv-2-2
member-a, serv-3-1

member-b, serv-4-1
member-b, serv-4-2
member-b, serv-5-1

member-c, serv-6-1
member-c, serv-7-1

member-h, serv-8-1
member-h, serv-8-2

member-z, serv-10-1
member-z, serv-10-2
member-z, serv-10-3
member-z, serv-11-1
```

And this is the type of random order I'm looking to get:

```
member-c, serv-6-1
member-c, serv-7-1

member-b, serv-4-1
member-b, serv-4-2
member-b, serv-5-1

member-z, serv-10-1
member-z, serv-10-2
member-z, serv-10-3
member-z, serv-11-1

member-a, serv-1-1
member-a, serv-1-2
member-a, serv-2-1
member-a, serv-2-2
member-a, serv-3-1

member-h, serv-8-1
member-h, serv-8-2
```

Comment: I don't understand. You want to keep the member_nbr/serv_nbr order, but you want a random order? That seems contradictory. Do you mean you get multiple rows per member_nbr/serv_nbr and you want to have random order of the rows inside each member_nbr/serv_nbr? That would simply be `ORDER BY member_nbr, serv_nbr, dbms_random.random`. Or is it something else that you want? In that case, what do you want? Show sample data, so we understand what you mean.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I get multiple rows per member_nbr/serv_nbr and need them ordered together for iteration purposes. However I would like those rows also randomized. I posted sample data and my desired result. I also tried your suggestion of `ORDER BY member_nbr, serv_nbr, dbms_random.random` but that did not produce the result I am looking for.

Comment: Ah, okay, you don't want to have random order within member_nbr, serv_nbr, but you want the member_nbr blocks in random order. I'll post an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have ordered your rows by member_nbr, serv_nbr. What you want instead is to have these member_nbr blocks in random order.

For this use a window function giving you a random number per member_nbr:

```
order by
  max(dbms_random.random) over (partition by member_nbr),
  serv_nbr;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/jD5vIKT5

Comment: Sorry I get the following error: "ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression"  when using that order by clause with my above query

Comment: That is weird. It should work, and I don't see any reason it doesn't. What Oracle version are you using?

Comment: Version 21.4.2.018

Comment: Okay, this is obviously a bug. So, you must put the `max(dbms_random.random) over (partition by member_nbr) as member_sortkey` into the select clause. This gives you a `member_sortkey` that you can use in `order by member_sortkey, serv_nbr`. Maybe use another CTE to do this in two steps, get your distinct data along with the sortkey, from there select your columns only and order by sortkey.

Comment: That worked when I moved it to the select clause

Answer (score 0):

Try it using Floor(dbms_random.value(1, n))

```sql
with 
    tbl AS
        (   Select  SYSDATE - Floor(LEVEL / 4) "A_DATE", LEVEL "A_NUMBER",
                    SubStr('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP', LEVEL, 1) "A_LETTER",
                    Floor(dbms_random.value(1, 3)) "A_RAND"
            From Dual
            Connect By LEVEL <= 6
        )
Select  *
From    tbl
Order By A_DATE,  A_RAND, A_NUMBER, A_LETTER

/*
1st run
A_DATE      A_NUMBER A_LE     A_RAND
--------- ---------- ---- ----------
01-OCT-23          4 D             2
01-OCT-23          5 E             2
01-OCT-23          6 F             2
02-OCT-23          2 B             1
02-OCT-23          1 A             2
02-OCT-23          3 C             2

6 rows selected. 

2nd run
A_DATE      A_NUMBER A_LE     A_RAND
--------- ---------- ---- ----------
01-OCT-23          4 D             1
01-OCT-23          5 E             1
01-OCT-23          6 F             2
02-OCT-23          1 A             1
02-OCT-23          2 B             2
02-OCT-23          3 C             2

6 rows selected. 
*/
```

The result depends on random number span (1, n) and on differencies in your data. You can adjust it by concatinating the random number to some of your column(s) too.